# Regular Expression: Match to (aa|bb) (cc)?

Tags: regex

My regular expression needs to be able to find the strings:

1. Visual Studio 2008
2. Visual Studio Express 2008
3. Visual Basic 2008
4. Visual Basic Express 2008
5. Visual C++ 2008
6. Visual C++ Express 2008

and a host of other similar variants, to be replaced with this one single string

> Visual Studio 2005

I tried "Visual (Basic|C++|Studio) (Express)? 2008", but it is not working. Any ideas?

***Edit***:
Now I have tried "Visual (Basic)|(C++)|(Studio) (Express )?2008", but the replaced line becomes "Visual Studio 2005 Express 2008" for the input "Visual Basic Express 2008".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be

```
"Visual (Basic|C\+\+|Studio)( Express)? 2008"

>>> import re
>>> repl = 'Visual Studio 2005'
>>> regexp = re.compile('Visual (Studio|Basic|C\+\+)( Express)? 2008')
>>> test1 = 'Visual Studio 2008'
>>> test2 = 'Visual Studio Express 2008'
>>> test3 = 'Visual C++ Express 2008'
>>> test4 = 'Visual C++ Express 1008'
>>> re.sub(regexp,repl,test1)
'Visual Studio 2005'
>>> re.sub(regexp,repl,test2)
'Visual Studio 2005'
>>> re.sub(regexp,repl,test3)
'Visual Studio 2005'
>>> re.sub(regexp,repl,test4)
'Visual C++ Express 1008'
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer. Sometimes regex can be a bit confusing :)

Answer (score 3):

In the case without an Express, you are looking for 2 spaces before the year.  That is no good.  Try this:

```
"Visual (Basic|C\+\+|Studio) (Express )?2008"
```

Depending on the input, it might be enough to use:

```
"Visual [^ ]+ (Express )?2008"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the special characters (like +). Also the 'express' bit, should have a space on either side.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
Visual (Basic|C\\+\\+|Studio) (Express )?2008
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless your sample input is riddled with all sorts of permutations of your keywords, you could simplify it immensely with this:

```
Visual .+? 2008
```

Comment: That would need a non greedy quantifier, in case your input has two 2008 instances... like Visual .+? 2008

Answer (score 1):

i think this should works

```
/visual (studio|basic|c\+\+)? (express)?\s?2008/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
Visual (Basic|C\+\+|Studio)( Express)? 2008
```

that is, quote the '+' of 'C++' and include the space in "Express"

Since it's Python and you don't need the parenthesized parts:

```
Visual (?:Basic|C\+\+|Studio)(?: Express)? 2008
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more explicit with spaces:

```
Visual\s(Basic|C\+\+|Studio)(\sExpress)?\s2008
```

Answer (score -1):

A very late answer, but like to answer.You can simply try this

```
/Visual.*2008/g
```

http://regex101.com/r/fI0yU1/1